# Angular Chart Doughnut Kind with multiple series

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I'm using the Angular Charts to plot a Doughnut chart; my code is structured as follows:

```
$scope.data = [
['abc', 'def'],
['fgh', 'ijk'],
];
$scope.labels = ['Ask', 'Bid'];
$socpe.series = ['Volume Ask', 'Volume Bid'];
$scope.color = ['#66ff33', '#ffff00'];
```

The code above results in something as the image bellow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2m2L.png

However, what I need to create is a chart where the colors would be shown as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6F0R.png

How we can see, the code is attributing a color per serie and I need a chart with two colors per serie.

Anyone knows if is there possible to create something like this using the Angular Charts?

Comment: Please provide more detailed code example. If possible - plunker / jsfiddle / ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set through this,

```
  $scope.datasetOverride = [{
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: [
        "#66ff33",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56"
      ]
    }, {
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: [
        "#ffff00",
        "#46BFBD",
        "#FDB45C"
      ]
    }];
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Krq0cKpN7UAJizsDruju?p=preview)**

Comment: @Sajeetharan your demo code is not working. Could you please have a look and update it. thanks